# Shared Numbervar malfunction

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with two sub reports. The subreports each have a total cost field that I want to pass into the main report, add together, and then subtract that value from the total project budget. A project number is the unifying link between the subreports and the main report. The idea is to get an accurate picture of the remaining budget for the project.
I am using shared numbervar to pass the values.

**In my subreport(s):**
WhilePrintingRecords;

Shared NumberVar POTotal := (Sum ({S_EPPS_PO_REPORT.PO_Line Cost}, {S_EPPS_PO_REPORT.Project Number}))

**In my main report:**
WhilePrintingRecords;

Shared NumberVar POTotal;

POTotal

It works as it should if I'm looking at a project that has not yet recorded charges on either subreport. However, If there is cost data in the subreport, the BudgetRemaining total in the FOLLOWING projects is subtracting the subreport cost from the previous project (sometimes two projects previous).

How can I ensure that the values passed from the subreports will ONLY apply to the BudgetRemaining formula when the project number is the same for each report?

Comment: The value of your shared variable will change as it progresses top-to-bottom in your report. Because of this you need your subreports to appear **only once** per project, your calculations/formulas involving those variables need to appear **after** the subreports, and you should reset the values to 0 at the beginning of each project group.

Comment: Thank you. Can you offer help on how to ensure the subreports are only used once per project? Also, how do I set it to reset values to 0 for each project?

Comment: Group by the project and place the subreports in the group header. Above the subreports, place a formula that sets `POTotal:=0`.

Comment: Ryan, thank you! I had the subreports in the header already, resetting the Shared NumVar to 0 prior to each report did the trick.